# on passing a pure function to a module

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Just wanted to check if it safe to do the following:

Lets say I have a function 'f(x)' that also depends on other parameters. For example, the function `a*Exp[ (x-x0)^2/(2*std^2)]`

From the UI I read the user input values (via sliders) for the parameters `a` and `x0` and `std`, then I make a pure function variable

```
 f=Function[{x,a,x0,std}, a*Exp[ (x-x0)^2/(2*std^2)]
```

The above is done in the same context (in the Manipulate control area), when I am reading the user input, then when the user hits a button to run the program, I call another lower level function to process this input, like this

```
 foo[f,a,x0,std]
```

then inside foo, it evaluates `f` over some grid points (x1,x2,etc...) by making calls like this

```
 foo[f_,a_,x0,std_]:=Module[{x1,x2...},     
   .....
   f[x1,a,x0,std];
   f[x2,a,x0,std];
   f[x3,a,x0,std]; etc... 
   ....
   ]
```

Notice that inside foo, only the `x` parameter to the pure function is used, the rest are just coming along for the ride.

But since they are not used inside foo, I am thinking of not passing all the other parameters a,x0,std.

So, I changed the pure function to become

```
 f=Function[{x}, a*Exp[ (x-x0)^2/(2*std^2)];
```

then called foo like this

```
 foo[f]
```

then inside foo, I do

```
 foo[f_]:=Module[{},     
   .....
   f[x1];
   f[x2];
   f[x3]; etc...
   ....
   ]
```

I tested this, and it works. (at first I thought since the context is different inside Module foo, I had to pass `a,x0,std` along with f. But I did not have to. It seems the `a`, `x0` and `stdx` values inside the pure function as saved as globals and passed in the pure function body.

My question: do you see any problem with the second approach above? something I am overlooking? in the tests I've done, it works fine so far. And it would make it much simpler, since now I only need to pass the pure function itself, and not pass all the other parameters used to build up, since they are not needed inside foo.

In other words, I am trying to decide between these 2 setups:

[image]

Just thought to check.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something along these lines:

```
mkf[a_, x0_, std_] := 
 Function[{x}, Evaluate[a*Exp[(x - x0)^2/(2*std^2)]]]

foo[f_] := Module[{x},
      x = 1;
      f[x]
      ]

foo[mkf[1, 1, 1]]
```

You generate the function you want to use before passing it onwards.

Comment: good idea. So you basically replaced the parameters by numbers, except for the x, so that when the pure function is passed, only x the free variable in it. Should be safer. How about in this case, if I use With to build f? as I show in my edit(1). Same idea as yours. seems to have the same result. thanks

Comment: With is fine too; in some cases you may be able to use Evaluate to get things simplified as much as possible. The point is to generate a new function that is independent of other variables.

Comment: Actually I tried With now, and it is not giving the exact looking FullForm as yours. Hard to read. But I'll stick with your method. Seems simpler. So I Evaluate it, this changes all the other parameters to numbers, and this seems much better. Do not need to worry about symbols in the body of the pure function. thanks.

Comment: +1 - I would have done it similarly (generate a closure with embedded constants). One thing though: since you use `Evaluate` (which is not strictly needed here), only the renaming of `x` to `x$`, done by (presumably) `SetDelayed / RuleDelayed`, saves `x` in the function body from accidental collisions with the possible global value for `x`. (which happens e.g. here: `x = 1;Function[{x}, Evaluate[a*Exp[(x - x0)^2/(2*std^2)]]]`). I don't know whether we can always count on renaming scheme in such cases, but one easy protective measure would be to wrap the r.h.s. of `mkf` into `Block[{x},...]`.

Comment: @Nasser You can use the method suggested here, also in case when your parameters are not known in advance, or you find it inconveneinet to generate a function beforehand: simply generate the function already inside the `Module`, and then apply it.

Comment: The fact that I used Evaluate[] was to show that this method actually can have the advantage that the function body can already at this stage be manipulated (optimized); you could generate a compiled function instead. Adding a Block[{x}] might be good, if you use global variables.